# How to execute a stored procedure in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_RATING 
(
  P_RID OUT NUMBER 
, P_STARS OUT NUMBER 
, P_DATE OUT DATE 
) AS 
BEGIN
SELECT RID, STARS, RATINGDATE 
INTO P_RID, P_STARS, P_DATE
FROM RATING;
END TEST_RATING;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that this procedure does what you want.  Unless you are guaranteed that there will always e exactly 1 row in the `rating` table, you'll get an error at runtime that your query either returns no rows or that it returns multiple rows.

If you are guaranteed that you'll always have exactly 1 row in `rating`, you can call this procedure in an anonymous PL/SQL block

```
DECLARE
  l_rid   number;
  l_stars number;
  l_date  date;
BEGIN
  test_rating( l_rid,
               l_stars,
               l_date );
END;
```

Of course, you'd probably want to do something with the data that is returned even if that is just calling `dbms_output.put_line` to write it to the `dbms_output` buffer.

Comment: Hi Justin, I want to multiple rows as output. What do I do for that?

Comment: @user1483598 - It depends on your requirements and what you plan on doing with the data.  You could write a procedure that has an OUT parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  It may make more sense, though, to create a view.  Or at least a function rather than a procedure that has an `OUT` parameter.